# Search multiple values from a string using SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate a sum of some values by searching from a string using SQL Query on specific criteria.

```
String=  'Cash/260 on 6/9/21, Cash/140 on 6/9/21, Cash/200+ 00923 on 6/9/21'
```

required result = 260 + 140 + 200

can anyone guide me?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string and parse it like this:

```
select s.*
from (select sum(try_convert(int, replace(replace(s.value, 'Cash/', ''), '+', ''))) as total
      from string_split('Cash/260 on 6/9/21, Cash/140 on 6/9/21, Cash/200+ 00923 on 6/9/21', ' ') s
      where s.value like 'Cash/%'
     ) s;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9eecb/128517) is a SQL-Fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, i got required result by your help